# Structure theorem of Artinian rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Can you help me with a complete proof of Structure theorem of Artinian rings? I find just partial proofs.

Comment: If you are aware of partial proofs, you could tell us which parts you are missing.

Comment: Do you mean “commutative Artinian rings”?

Comment: Yes , commutative

Comment: Just artinian? No other conditions? One solution has already assumed you mean semisimple artinian rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof goes like this:

- Show that any prime ideal is maximal.
- Show that there only finitely many maximal ideals.
- Use Chinese Remainder Theorem to deduce that the ring is isomorphic to the finite product of factors $R/\mathfrak m_i^{r_i}$, where $\mathfrak m_i$ are the maximal ideals.

Which of these steps is not clear to you?

Comment: The final statement is of course wrong: can you check with $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, which is not a product of fields?

Comment: Corrected the final statement.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a prime ideal $I$ of $A$; then $A/I$ is an artinian integral domain, therefore a field.

Indeed, if $D$ is an artinian integral domain and $a\in D$, $a\ne0$, you can consider the descending chain $aD\supseteq a^2D\supseteq\dotsb$. Since $D$ is artinian, $a^nD=a^{n+1}D$, for some $n$. Then $a^n=a^{n+1}b$ and so $a$ is invertible.

There are only finitely many maximal ideals. Indeed, if you consider $J$ a minimal element in the set of intersections of finitely many maximal ideals, you can say $J=I_1\cap I_2\cap\dots\cap I_n$, for some (pairwise distinct) maximal ideals $I_1,\dots,I_n$. Let $I$ be a maximal ideal. Then, by minimality of $J$, $J\cap I=J$, because also $J\cap I$ is the intersection of finitely many maximal ideals. Thus $J\subseteq I$ and so, from
$$
I_1\cap I_2\cap\dots I_n\subseteq I
$$
we get $I_k\subseteq I$, for some $k$. By maximality of $I_k$, equality follows. In particular, $\{I_1,\dots,I_n\}$ is the full set of maximal ideals.

Now consider the obvious map
$$
A\to\prod_{k=1}^n A_{I_k}
$$
from $A$ to the product of all localizations at the maximal ideals. Prove this is an isomorphism.

Comment: A hint to prove that the last map is an isomorphism is to prove that the localization of the map in each maximal ideal is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

*Commutative Algebra: With a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*, By *David Eisenbud*, [corollary 2.16](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fm_yPgZBucMC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=Structure+theorem+of+Artinian+rings&source=bl&ots=7Cm6zxU0Jh&sig=9r9uwD5EHEqDwzY8QgyFZWATEOM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTvabSnIvLAhXiKnIKHUx0BHoQ6AEITTAH#v=onepage&q&f=false) has: *Any Artinian ring is a finite direct product of local Artinian rings.*
see also [this](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math205bS10/Math205b_S10_82.pdf).
You can see also [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~julia/teaching/506_Spring2010/WK2_Jim.pdf) for complete proof and uniqueness (1.9).

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: one can at least see Eisenbud' book anyway.